# How to use grep in shell with -e option set

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In bash -e option stops executing after an error and grep commands returns a non-zero status in case it does not find for the pattern it is looking for.
I want to use grep inside an if statement, something like

```
#/bin/bash -e
if [[ `grep str /usr/lib/file.txt` -eq 0 ]]
  //do something
fi
```

If i use $? to get the statement of last command, then the execution stops after last command as grep returns non-zero status.
There must be some way to accomplish this, need help finding it

Comment: A **checked exit** -- that is, the exit status of a command which is either an `if` condition or part of a short-circuiting operation such as `&&` or `||` -- is ignored by `set -e` -- if that weren't true, you could never use an `if` statement at all with it enabled!

Comment: Your question says "If I use `$?` to get the [exit status] of [the] last command", but the code in your question isn't using `$?` at all. You might want to be sure that the code you're showing actually represents your problem.

Comment: ...that said, you should consider reading [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and understanding its caveats before making the decision to use `set -e`; this feature is... quite controversial, and has a long history of incompatible changes trying to patch around surprising corner cases, with the effect that different releases of bash can behave differently with it enabled.

Comment: Reading BashFAQ thanks a ton for all the guidance @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it in-place:

```
#/bin/bash -e
if grep -q str /usr/lib/file.txt; then
    echo "Found str"
else 
    echo "Didn't find str"
fi
```

Note the `-q` (`--quiet`) option of `grep`, we are only interested in the exit status.

Comment: if grep -q str /usr/lib/file.txt returns -1 and script execution is stopping there, next statement is not getting executed

Comment: @user1560339, that doesn't happen with the code in heemayl's answer here. If you're getting that behavior, then you're doing something different.

Comment: @heemayl, you might want to replace your comments with actual `echo "found str"` or `echo "didn't find str"` commands, just to be sure the syntax is valid in a copy/paste scenario (since right now those comments need to be filled in for the code to parse).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Done.

Comment: @user1560339, ...and by the way, it's `1`, not `-1` that's returned when no match is found -- exit status is of the type `unsigned char`, meaning the only possible values (for a regular exit, as opposed to a signal) are between 0 and 255.

Comment: @heemayl Thanks a lot, i was trying to sew with a sword, this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You're missing the `; then`

   ```
   if [[ `grep str /usr/lib/file.txt` -eq 0 ]]; then
       //do something
       echo Yes
   fi
   ```
2. When I tried it in a bash shell, and `str` existed, I saw the matching lines on the screen.  You probably don't want that.  Pipe grep into `wc` (word count) with the `-l` option (only return number of lines):

   ```
   if [[ `grep str /usr/lib/file.txt | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]; then
      //do something
      echo Yes 
   fi
   ```

Comment: Use the `{}` button, or four-space indents, to format multi-line blocks of code. Backticks are for stretches smaller than a single line.

Comment: The other thing is that the code here is unnecessarily inefficient: If `file.txt` is several GB, your answer here will read through the whole thing, whereas [the answer by heemayl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41009682/14122) will stop as soon as the first instance of `str` is found; if that first answer is found early in the file, that can be a huge difference in runtime. If there's an advantage to this answer I'm missing (or, generally, any particular reason to prefer an approach over those given in preexisting answers), consider calling it out.

Comment: I went ahead and reformatted this, without changing content. At minimum, though, one content change you might consider is changing `//`-style comments to `#` ones (which bash actually recognizes).